# Why do Guava classes provide so many factory methods instead of just one that takes varargs?

Tags: java, guava, variadic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Guava's ImmutableList have so many overloaded of() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737882/why-does-guavas-immutablelist-have-so-many-overloaded-of-methods)

Looking at Guava's [ImmutableList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r12/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) (and some other classes), you'll find plenty of overloaded `of` convenience methods ("Returns an immutable list containing the given elements, in order.") that take a different number of parameters:

```
...
public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3) 
public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4) 
public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5) 
...
```

All the way to this one:

```
public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1,
                                      E e2,
                                      E e3,
                                      E e4,
                                      E e5,
                                      E e6,
                                      E e7,
                                      E e8,
                                      E e9,
                                      E e10,
                                      E e11,
                                      E e12,
                                      E... others)
```

Some colleagues of mine consider this silly, wondering why there's isn't just one method: `of(E... elements)`.  They suspect it's an ill-guided performance "optimisation" that falls into the category "do you think you're smarter than compiler", or something like that.

My hunch is that Kevin Bourrillion et al. put these methods in there for a real reason. Can anyone explain (or speculate) what that reason might be?

Comment: If the library were older I would suspect the methods were written pre Java 5.0.  The original code might be that old and it hasn't been refactored.

Comment: @Peter: Never mind the fact that it would break backwards compatibility to remove them (the code would be linked against a method which no longer exists), which they may not want.  Though they could at least be deprecated were that so.

Comment: @Mark, ironically, it is the of(E[]) builder which is deprecated. ;)

Comment: @Colin, you're right, it's a duplicate. (I had a vague idea I'd read about this somewhere earlier, and this is the reason... :P)

Comment: @Peter: `of(E[])` is deprecated in favor of the more descriptive `copyOf(E[])` I believe. And I don't think there's anything in Guava that uses a pre-1.5 style.

Comment: "Some colleagues of mine consider this silly..."  I smiled, because no one finds it sillier than we who actually DID it. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comment in the [source](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java) says:

```
// These go up to eleven. After that, you just get the varargs form, and
// whatever warnings might come along with it. :(
```

So, this was done because varargs methods produce a warning with generic arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's to avoid `unchecked generic array creation` warning when `E` is a generic type.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was the reason, but it's certainly a relevant consideration.  It's stupid, but currently in Java you get this warning when you *call* a varargs method using a generic type, which is ridiculous since as the caller you can never interact with the array created by invoking the method via varargs.  I believe either Java 7 or 8 will introduce a change to move the warning to the method declaration instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's to avoid the overhead of creating a varargs array for the most common use cases.  This is modeled after the way [EnumSet.of(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#of%28E%29) was designed.

Comment: I can't be so, because these methods call the same vararg method internally.

Comment: There is a chapter talking about that in Effective Java, but I don't seem to be able to find it on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Actaully the compiler is really dumb, the JVM has most of the smarts, but its still not smart enough to eliminate the need to create an array for a vararg.

Whether saving the array is really worth it, is perhaps something the author didn't want users to worry about. i.e. he might know it doesn't make much difference, but not all users might realise its not worth worrying about it 99% of the time.

When it was google-collections this was part of the description "High-performance immutable implementations of the standard collection types, for example ImmutableSet"

Comment: Vararg parameters _are_ arrays, so of course it isn't possible to not create an array for a varargs argument. Anyway, `ImmutableList` constructs the varargs array internally for all of these overloads (with the exception of the single-element list).

Answer (score -1):

What I can think of is to avoid confusion by the compiler.

If we had only,

```
public static ImmutableList<E> of(E element); //Option 1
```

and

```
public static ImmutableList<E> of(E... elements);  //Option 2
```

and in your code we had

```
ImmutableList<String> list = ImmutableList.of("Value");
```

The compiler wouldn't know whether to call option 1 or option 2.

There must be a valid reason why Josh Bloch, Kevin Bourrillion and his team thought of having "ridiculous" `of(...)` method.

Comment: The compiler will use the most specific method matching the call... in this case, Option 1.

Comment: Plus, if that were all that was needed, it would just take an overload like `of(E, E, E...)`.