# Equivalient method overload why necessary?

Tags: java, performance, theory

I browsed some JAVA code made by Google, and I found the ImmutableSet: http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html

They implemented the of() method with several other ways:

```
public static <E> ImmutableSet<E> of(E e1, E e2);
public static <E> ImmutableSet<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3);
public static <E> ImmutableSet<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4);
public static <E> ImmutableSet<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5);
public static <E> ImmutableSet<E> of(E... elements);
```

I checked the implementation which is here:https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.java

There's a create method wiith the following signature:

```
private static <E> ImmutableSet<E> create(E... elements)
```

which wraps the

```
private static <E> ImmutableSet<E> create(Iterable<? extends E> iterable, int count);
```

method. The public methods just passes the parameters to the create(E... elements) signatured method which finally calls the other create method.

I guess that the public of methods with fixed count of parameter are unnecessary since we have the of(E... elements) method.

My question is that why did they do that like this? Performance? Or it's a pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: Side-note: If you're using the old Google Collections library, don't, it's not supported anymore. Use the new and shiny [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) which supersedes the Google Collections (and is actively developed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be related to performance, actually: All the methods delegate to the same creation method, which expects an array anyhow.

My guess is that it is related to warnings. Consider the following, minimal snippet:

```
import java.util.List;

class ImmutableSet<T>
{
}
public class ParametersTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> list0 = null;
        List<String> list1 = null;
        of(list0, list1);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <E> ImmutableSet<E> of(E e1, E e2) {
        return create(e1, e2);
    }

    public static <E> ImmutableSet<E> of(E... elements) {
        return create(elements);
    }

    private static <E> ImmutableSet<E> create(E... elements) 
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The call to `of` in the main method is fine: It matches the 2-args-version of the `of` method. Now comment out the 2-args-version of the `of`-method. Then the call is still OK, but will directly invoke the varags version. This will cause a generic array to be created, and cause a warning. (This warning is suppressed in the 2-args-version, obviously).

So to summarize, I assume that this is in order to avoid warnings for clients of the library who want to invoke the `of` method with several objects of a generic type.

Fortunately, things like this will no longer be necessary in the future, thanks to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html

Comment: You're right. I found this around one minute ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314883/why-do-guava-classes-provide-so-many-factory-methods-instead-of-just-one-that-ta?rq=1  So my question is actually duplication, sorry for that, but this answer shows that this way is forwarded because of the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Performance.  In order to call the E... version of the method, the caller must allocate a new array.  The caller only has to push the args on the stack to call the other methods.

Comment: But they still call the variadic version of `create`, so an array will be created either way, no?

Comment: If code is JIT compiled, and the compiler is any good, it will likely pass some or all of the args in registers, assuming the method is not recursive.

Comment: @AlexD I'm pretty sure the JIT compiler can't do that with a variadic method.

Comment: @sepp2k, if the compiler is good, there's no reason why not. At any given call site, the number of args passed is a known constant. Call-site specialization -- a *very* powerful optimization which can make a lot of programs much faster. Whether a given JVM actually does that kind of optimization or not is another question, and I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

They do it to manage memory in a more efficient way. If you have an immutable collection with a small set of items, it is better to explicitly fix the size of the collection. Otherwise, Java will create a collection of a size that is bigger. E.g: A HashSet, unless specified otherwise will have an intial size of 12 entries.

Comment: AFAIK, an immutable collection will _always_ be sized appropriatelly to the number of elements inserted, no matter what method you use to instantiate it. And a default HashSet will have a size of 16 (to allow for a trick of using binary `AND` instead of a `mod` operation when calculating the right bucket from the `hashCode`). Or has anything changed recently?

Comment: Since all of the mentioned overloads of `of` call the exact same `create` method, I don't see how they could possibly do anything differently (like fixing the size).

Comment: You're right. I missed the part where it delegates to a unique method in the end.