# Why does the library contain both Stream.of(T t) and Stream.of(T... values)?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Since the method

```
Stream.of(T... values)
```

includes the case of a single element, why is the method:

```
Stream.of(T t)
```

also included in the API? What's its purpose? When is it invoked? Does it do anything different from the varargs version?

Comment: For the same reason as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924249/why-does-enumset-have-many-overloaded-of-methods

Answer (score 7):

> What's its purpose?

A small improvement in efficiency for a common use case.

> When is it invoked?

When you have one argument.

> Does it do anything different from the varargs version?

The out come is the same, but it creates less garbage.

Comment: This also explains `Stream.empty()`, though that doesn't work as implicitly as an overload.

Comment: @shmosel And `empty()` is much clearer semantically than what looks like a missing argument.

Comment: @chrylis Guava doesn't think so.

Comment: @chrylis You can still use `Stream.of()` but I agree that `empty()` is a clearer choice.