# What type of list is generated by List.of() in Java

Tags: java, list, collections

```
Employee john = new Employee("John", "Brown", 32, 100);
Employee camila = new Employee("Camila", "Smith", 25, 101);
Employee pat = new Employee("Pat", "Hanson", 23, 102);

List<Employee> employeeList = List.of(john, camila, pat);
```

What type of `List` is generated by the `List.of()` method. Is it an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`?

Comment: Neither. It's a good idea to look at the implementation of that method.

Comment: It is similar to an `ArrayList`, in that it is a list backed by an array. However, it does not have the same runtime properties as a `java.util.ArrayList`, e.g. it is immutable.

Comment: Why is this important?  Regardless of the implementation, you will be treating the returned object as a List instance.

Comment: @VGR for performace reasons.

Comment: OK where the hell can I find the java src now that grepcode is nolonger a thing.

Comment: If you need an ArrayList, make an ArrayList.  You can use `new ArrayList<>(List.of(john, camila, pat))`, for instance.  Regardless of what List.of happens to return right now, future Java versions are free to change it.

Answer (score 14):

Neither. According to the docs for [`List.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) it returns:

> Returns an immutable list containing an arbitrary number of elements.

Note that it is the *interface* [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) that `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` implement

If we run this code:

```
List<Integer> listOf = List.of(1,2,3);
System.out.println(listOf.getClass());
```

We get:

```
class java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN
```

Comment: the variable of type List is just a pointer to an actual object which should be an instance of some class I think, right? So what is the underlying class type?

Comment: @mettleap The class type is `class java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN`

Comment: class java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN - An immutable implementation of a List<E> with a variable amount of elements

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Employee> employeeList = List.of(john, camila, pat);
```

is more or less equals to

```
List<Employee> employeeList = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(john, camila, pat));
```

In case you warry about concrete implementation of the `List`, do it your own, this is much better.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the different [`List#of` methods in the OpenJDK source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/70359afda5d0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/List.java#l778).

(The pattern was obviously inspired by the corresponding Guava classes. See [Why does Guava's ImmutableList have so many overloaded of() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737882/why-does-guavas-immutablelist-have-so-many-overloaded-of-methods) )

The method that is **not** specialized for a certain number of arguments creates an instance of [`ImmutableCollections.ListN`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/70359afda5d0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#l223), which internally just stores a copy (!) of the varargs-array and provides straightforward implementations of the `List` methods to access the array.

But as others have pointed out: **The exact type should not matter!**

The only point that might matter is that the returned list also implements [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html). Although this does not seem to be specified explicitly in the [documentation for unmodifiable lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), it's something that I'd personally rely on. They'll never change this to become some sort of linked list or so...

Answer (score 0):

List.of() as a static factory method returns a basic immutable implementation of List.

Visit https://4comprehension.com/the-curious-case-of-jdk9-immutable-collections/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure as i'm still learning, but just relying on the basics

similar to static methods in Math class for example

> int value = Math.sqrt(9) ; //which is a static function that just returns a value

- in this case `List.of(john, camila, pat);`  is also a static function and just returns a list and doesn't have any state nor behavior.

I realized the below both are not same , as one is assigning an object of Array-list type and the other is simply calling a static function and creating  the list.

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

List<Employee> employeeList = List.of(john, camila, pat);
```