# Java 8 Stream usage

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to filter the list of objects using stream.

```
public class MyObj{
    private String ID;
    private String version;
}
MyObj obj1=new MyObj("bike","1.8");
MyObj obj2=new MyObj("bike","2.0");
MyObj obj3=new MyObj("car","3.4");
MyObj obj4=new MyObj("car","4.6");
List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(obj1);
list.add(obj2);
list.add(obj3);
list.add(obj4);
List<MyObj> filteredData=list.stream(). filter(s1,s2-> { if(s1.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(s2.getId()))
 //** I stucked here ,not understanding how to compare objects in stream" **//
```

`List<Myobj> list` (contains all the mentioned objects above).
I want to filter it in such a way that it returns a list containing distinct ID's of highest version.
Example: It should return `List` of objects. Here it should return `obj2`, `obj4`.

Please help.

I have tried using private methods to filter my list by passing ID and list of objects as a parameters. It will return list of objects of certain ID with highest version. And finallym I am cumulating all the lists to a single list.
And I am expecting to do this using a stream if possible.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please show your best effort attempt to solve this and describe how it's not working.

Comment: Hi Bohemian,I tried to write using stream but i couldn't able to complete so I used some private methods to compare the versions and return the list.i wanted to know whether we can do it using stream.

Comment: *i wanted to know whether we can do it using stream.* Yes, you can

Comment: Abra thank you so much for sharing the code,it's helpful.Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public record MyObj(String id, String version) {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(List.of(new MyObj("bike","1.8"),
                                   new MyObj("bike","2.0"),
                                   new MyObj("car","3.4"),
                                   new MyObj("car","4.6"))
                               .stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.id(),
                                                              Collectors.maxBy((o1, o2) -> o1.version().compareTo(o2.version()))))
                               .values());
    }
}
```

`MyObj` lends itself to being a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

In the above code, I first create a `List` of `MyObj` instances using method [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051646/what-type-of-list-is-generated-by-list-of-in-java) (that was added in JDK 9).

Then I create a [`Stream<MyObj>`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

Method `groupingBy` returns a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html).

First argument to method `groupingBy` is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) that provides the `Map` key.

Second argument to method `groupingBy` works on a `Stream<List<MyObj>>`. Hence `maxBy` will return the maximum element in each `List` element of the `Stream` and the maximum element is determined by the [`Comparator`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable). In the above code, the `Comparator` compares the `version` member of each `MyObj` instance in a given `List`.

The result is a `Map` where the key is the `id` (of a `MyObj` object) and the value is the largest `version`.

Finally, calling method `values` on the `Map` returns a `List` of the `Map` values where each value is wrapped in an [`Optional`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html).

Running above code produces following:

```
[Optional[MyClass[id=car, version=4.6]], Optional[MyClass[id=bike, version=2.0]]]
```

Online demonstration available [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/M4Z).