Method overloads with vararg
When designing a (performant) method with variable parameter length like
<T> void consume(T t1)
<T> void consume(T t1, T t2)
<T> void consume(T t1, T t2, T t3)

and a) another overload with vararg at the end e.g. ImmutableList.of()
<T> void consume(T t1, T t2, T t3, T... others)

or b) another overload with single vararg parameter e.g. List.of()
<T> void consume(T... tees)

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each vararg overload?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918934/what-is-the-point-of-overloaded-convenience-factory-methods-for-collections-in-j

@SotiriosDelimanolis The question is not about the telescoping overloads. OP is asking about the final varargs variant, whether there's a meaningful difference between collapsing the entire arg set vs. reserving varargs for the remainder.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737882/why-does-guavas-immutablelist-have-so-many-overloaded-of-methods

no real difference between a) and b) regarding the calling of the methods, since the most specific method will be chosen (they will only be called when 3 or more arguments are given.) There is a difference on the method implementation side: a) needs to handle two values and an array; b) only the array (without knowing what the methods do, no advantages/disadvantages.) ...

... from the developers/readers view there is a (small) difference: a) is (almost) clearly only used when 3 or more arguments are given; with b) the 1- and 2-parameter declaration can be overseen and only the vararg declaration be considered

The problem with void consume(T... tees) is that it's all syntax sugar. This:
void consume(T... tees) {
  ....
}

consume(a, b);

is that this is compiled to:
void consume(T... tees) {
  ....
}

consume(new Object[] {a, b});

and the 'cost' is the creation of that 2-element array. This isn't a high cost, and in general 'performant' is simply not something you can reason out like this: Hotspot is far, far more complex than you think it is, so, you really need a profiler report before you just blindly assuming that making that 2-args array is actually a performance issue.
The point of having a stack of methods with increasing amounts of arguments until you get to the varargs one is that you avoid this array creation. However, the style you show is slightly wrong. This is right:
void consume(T a) { ??? }
void consume(T a, T b) { ??? }
void consume(T a, T b, T c, T... rest) { ??? }

In other words, you keep adding an argument, and once you feel you've got enough, the last one also gets the T... rest. You don't want both consume(T a, T b,  T c) as well as (T a, T b, T c, T... rest) because that means a call of the form consume(x, y, z) is ambiguous (are you calling the first one, or the second one with zero 'rest' args, which is valid java?)
So when do you 'stop' and just go with varargs? Well, you tell me: When the point of trying to save on that array allocation is no longer worth doing; some combination of 'if you're passing a bajillion args anyway, performance is probably out the window' and 'passing 12 args to this method is extremely rare so not worth trying to optimize for'.
In general you should just write one method (consume(T... tees)) and not bother with all those overloads. The JVM is very good at optimizing common patterns, and varargs are a very common pattern. Having the overloads is annoying to maintain, harder to document, and also adds API annoyances - if I happen to have an array of T elements I Can now no longer call your API.

I think you're missing the question. See my comment above.

If it's specifically about that final varargs method, I explained it in this answer. Having both void foo(T... args) as well as void foo(T a, T b, T c) means method calls are ambiguous and that's rarely what you want. For example, now you can't call  foo(null) anymore, and inference of T is more problematic than it needs to be. The one varargs method has more 'normal' args than any other version, just like I showed in the example in this answer.

There is no performance issue here. It's a compiler errors and confusion issue: It's more likely that users of your library will get confusing error messages if you write void foo(T... args); that is why you only want to write void foo(T a, T b, T c, T oneMoreThanAnyOtherHas, T... rest) with varargs and no others.

Effective Java 3rd Ed. Item 53: Use varargs judiciously shows following example:
public void foo(int a1, int a2, int a3) { } and right after
public void foo(int a1, int a2, int a3, int... rest) { }. Couldn't it be that the original example was also correct?

@bjmi It's a fine source, but in the end Joshua Bloch is still, last I checked, mortal and fallible. Fact: Those 2 signatures are ambiguous if you attempt to call them with 3 args. Sure, the java spec dictate which one 'wins', but, that's true if void foo(int... rest) also existed. Making the varargs one have 1 more non-var-args argument than any other means now all methods are 100% unambiguous. "But... appeal to authority!" is a logical fallacy. I don't have my copy of EJ on hand, but I've read it a few times; I cannot recall any objective defensive of the choice.
